# Merging two objects or more and display their sum

Tags: c#

i would like to merge the two objects and display their sum in the new object

The first i want to achieve is i have two object that have a 100 target sales and then the result must be 200.

The second i want to achieve is the two object has array and the array consist different value. 
if the two object is merge the value of the array in the new object   is the value of the two objects

simple example of my class

```
public class IncentivePayout
    {
        public decimal Sales { get; set; }

        public List<IncentivePayoutDetail> IncentivePayoutDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

```
public class IncentivePayoutDetail
    {
        public string ProductFamilyName { get; set; }

    }
```

example

```
 totalEthical: {
            target: 100,
            incentivePayoutDetails: [
                {

                    productFamilyName: X,
                },
                ]

 totalConsumer: {
            target: 100,
            incentivePayoutDetails: [
                {

                    productFamilyName: Y,
                },
                ]
```

the result i want to achieve is

```
 newObject: {
            target: 200,
            incentivePayoutDetails: [
                {

                    productFamilyName: X,
                },
                {

                    productFamilyName: Y,
                },
                ]
```

Comment: Is this an json or a class?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please show what you have tried so far.

Comment: this are c# objects

Comment: Would you add your classes on the question?

Comment: yup. i had a classes. sure. this are c# objects that become api

Comment: I suggest you to use class operators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here's my solution. Pretty straightforward. [Link to codeshare.](https://codeshare.io/G6KKEO)
I assumed how your classes might look like. If there are any inconsistencies, try to modify it to your needs.

If codeshare doesn't work. :

```
class Ethical{
    public int SomeValue = {get;private set;}
    public List<PayoutDetails> details = {get; private set;}

    public Ethical(int SomeValue){
    this.SomeValue = SomeValue;
    this.details = new List<PayoutDetails>();
  }

  public Ethical(){
    this.SomeValue = 0;
    this.details = new List<PayoutDetails>();
  }

  public void AddPayoutDetails(PayoutDetails details){
    this.details.add(details);
  }

  public void AddPayoutDetails(List<PayoutDetails> details){
    details.ForEach(el => this.details.Add(el));
  }

  public void AddToValue(int anyNumber){
    SomeValue += anyNumber;
  }

}


//for merging 2 objects
public static Ethical sumEthicalProperties(Ethical obj1, Ethical obj2){
    Ethical newObj = new Ethical(obj1.SomeValue + obj2.SomeValue)
  newObj.Add(obj1.details);
  newObj.Add(obj2.details);
  return newObj;
}

//MoreUniversal
public static Ethical sumEthicalProperties(params Ethical[] objs){

  int fullSum = 0;
  Ethical newObj = new Ethical()
  foreach(Ethical singleObj in objs){
    fullSum += singleObj.SomeValue;
    newObj.AddPayoutDetails = singleObj.details;
  }
  newObj.AddToValue(fullSum;
  return newObj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for putting in an answer, please add the C# code into your question, as link may broke over time.

Comment: Thanks for the idea Oleg Musjenko. my problem is now solved